# get imageView width and height in service class

Tags: android

I have a view in service and and imageview inside the view. When i get the width and height of that image the result is 0. PLease help. The view is defined in service class.

Thank you

Comment: As I know, your messing a bit the concepts. You should not use view elements inside a service because the service is meant to do background work and not to display or carry views. From the beginning your approach is not that good.

Comment: As per the requirement, i have to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this You need to understand the concept of UI thread in android...

Use this..

```
    yourView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // get the Width and height of the yourView Here.
        }
    });
```

Comment: It worked. Without knowing the concept, some people mark negative for the questions. Thanks buddy